# How to determine the price of writing an iOS curriculum

Tags: consulting, writing

I am working with a client where I will have to write the curriculum for an iOS course. The curriculum will consists of the flow of the iOS course (4-5 weeks) course and also the assignments. The course will not have any descriptive articles as they can be found on the web.

So mainly the course consists of assignments. There is a chance that the course will have video lectures but for that I will have to charge extra not sure how much.

Any ideas how I should proceed with this? Should I break down each assignment a separate charge and each lecture a separate charge?

Answer (score 1):

You have basically three possibilities

**Cost based:**

The most common mode for freelancers: Just calculate you hourly cost including desired profit and multiply by hours spent.

**Market based:**

Price it on, what a similar Product or Service would cost elsewhere i.e. what its worth in the market is. You do this usually when you can sell you product multiple times, so one customer does not have the bear the full cost. Make sure you cover your cost including increased overhead and a risk-margin once you reached your sales-goals.

**Revenue Sharing:**

If you are pretty convinced of the product, can afford to risk a little bit and want to create a sustainable long-term income. You could, for example, take a small license fee per student. This has the greatest earning-potential but also the greatest risk.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Do you think it would be wise to charge per item basis. Like if in iOS week 1 there are 5 assignments then each assignment will cost $150. If there is a video lecture for each item then video lecture will be $250. What do you think?

Comment: Part of beeing a freelancer is figuring that out for yourself. We don´t know you market or you financial background! If you are good at  your craft but bad at the business-end, I recommend to find fixed employment.